# Query Athena (Add Partition) using using AWS Glue Scala

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-athena, aws-glue

Is there a possibility to query the data to ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION in existing table in Athena, from Glue Script using Scala?

and possible libraries extending from aws.athena.connections (OR)

Using spark to query the Athena table to add from (Glue Data Catalog) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can [make a call to Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/APIReference/API_StartQueryExecution.html) with `ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION` query or [add partition via Glue API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions.html#aws-glue-api-catalog-partitions-CreatePartition). However, AWS SDK should be already provided for you by Glue so you can use appropriate [Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/athena/AmazonAthena.html#startQueryExecution-com.amazonaws.services.athena.model.StartQueryExecutionRequest-) or [Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/glue/AWSGlueClient.html#createPartition-com.amazonaws.services.glue.model.CreatePartitionRequest-) client classes.

If your jobs are running in custom VPC please make sure there is access to AWS services.